# Error when adding a user to MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Getting validation error when trying to sign up new user to database. Not sure where to go from here

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: [true, 'cannot be empty']},
    lastName: {type: String, required: [true, 'cannot be empty']},
    email: { type: String, required: [true, 'cannot be empty'], unique: [true, 'this email address has been used'] },
    password: { type: String, required: [true, 'cannot be empty'] },
}
);

//replace plaintext password
//pre middleware

userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    let user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password'))
        return next();
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => next(error));
  });

//comparison of password and hash

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(loginPassword) {
    return bcrypt.compare(loginPassword, this.password);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Error :
ValidationError: User validation failed: password: cannot be empty, email: cannot be empty, lastName: cannot be empty, firstName: cannot be empty
   at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Dominick\Desktop\4166\Dominick Project 3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2696:32)
   at C:\Users\Dominick\Desktop\4166\Dominick Project 3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2516:17
   at C:\Users\Dominick\Desktop\4166\Dominick Project 3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1238:9
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

Answer (score 1):

You need datas !

In your code you can't put empty fields, so just running this code in NodeJS won't work. try to create an object containing the datas.